# I bought Bit Coins while on a Bidding site. They were bought with my Credt card. How do I trace them?

Tags: websites, bitcoin-economy, network

I bought Bit coins on a Bidding site that only used Bit Coins. I never used them. How can I find them?  This was almost 6 years ago. It was $10.00 worth and that bought 10 bitcoins... Thanks

Comment: do you remember the website you bought it from ? or your private key ? or did you buy it from an exchange ? if yes, which exchange ? you can log back in to exchange if you still have the login details

Answer (score 1):

You can go back and check your credit card records for the purchase.  That should at least give you a name of a company.  Contact that company (if they still exist), and see if they can give you access (assuming you lost your credentials).  If they can, and they were storing your bitcoin for you, then you can transfer it to a wallet you control.  If you already transferred then out when you bought them, but lost the key/password/data to your wallet...then you are just out of luck.